# How can I remote control music on my computer from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to change, play or pause my music using my iPhone while it is playing on my laptop.

Comment: I'm not sure the question title really states the issue. I've had a go at re-wording it but if I've changed the intent of your question, please feel free to revert my edit or reword it yourself.

Comment: Which music player do you use?

Answer (score 22):

Get [Remote](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/remote/id284417350?mt=8) from the App Store which lets you control iTunes playback on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Another app to try is Mobile Mouse, which is an iPhone app and a server app you install on your computer. I prefer it to Apple's remote, and it adds the ability to launch any program from the dock, use Fkeys, a trackpad, and has iPod-like controls for iTunes.

It's a paid app, but there's a free version (Mobile Mouse Free) with similar features.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "VLC Remote": "VLC Remote® turns your iDevice into a remote control for VLC media player."

http://hobbyistsoftware.com/vlc-more

I use this on my iPhone and control VLC on a Mac Mini over WIFI, which is connected to my amplifier. It is very intuitive. A very useful little feature is the pause function, when the iPhone is ringing.

Answer (score -3):

You can use Spotify. The music player has also a remote control. Start the app on iPhone and Windows/Mac than you can see  on the status your iPhone or Mac. The function called Spot remote

> Spot Remote is the leading remote control for Spotify, allowing you to control your music over the air from your iPhone, iPod Touch or iPad. It is what Spotify has been missing.